# how to move button right in html

Tags: html, css

In my website I a have created popup for inserting user Details. In this form I am using two button one is for save and another one is for Cancel popup. And I want to move both button right hand side of page.
Both button placed in separate `tr` with `td`.

I used `style="width: 100px; float:right;"`

But no changes.

**My modal Popup Code**

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="myModalprofilepopup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"
        CancelControlID="btnclose" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" Style="display: none">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="Button2" Height="20px" Width="20px" runat="server" AlternateText="Close" ImageUrl="~/Images/Cancele_ButoonPNG.PNG" />--%>
        </div>
        <%--<div class="registrationFormAlert" style="color:green;" id="CheckPasswordMatch"></div>--%>
        <b style="font-size: 25px">FAV-VS Add New User</b><br />
        <br />
        <table id="NewAddItems">
            <tr id="trAddNew">
                <td>
                    <table border="0" class="width100p">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table class="width100p">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>User ID</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="width50p input-tb" style="width: 200px" id="txtUserIDAU" placeholder="Please Enter User ID" maxlength="15" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td><b>User Name</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="width50p input-tb" style="width: 200px" id="txtUserNameAU" placeholder="Please Enter User Name" maxlength="150" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Password</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="width50p input-tb" style="width: 200px" id="txtPasswordAU" required="required" maxlength="30" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td><b>Confirm Password</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="width50p input-tb" style="width: 200px" id="txtConfimPasswordAU" maxlength="150" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span id="CheckPasswordMatch" style="color: red;"></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp;<b>Status</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="radio" name="Status" checked="checked" value="Active" /><label for="first"><b>&nbsp;Active</b></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <input type="radio" name="Status" value="Inactive" /><label for="first"><b>&nbsp;In Active</b></label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;<b>Plant</b><span class="requierdField">*&nbsp;</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="width: 100px; float:right;">
                                 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return validatepopup();" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-success" />
                                 <asp:Button ID="btnclose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btn-danger" />
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**Button Code**

```
<tr>
  <td style="width: 100px; float:right;">
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return validatepopup();" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-success" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnclose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btn-danger" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Screen Shots**

[image]

Comment: probably `<td style="width: 100px; float:right;">` should be `<td style="text-align:right;" colspan="4">`

Comment: This is not asp related. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve] WITHOUT asp

Comment: @llya Bursov Thanx its working now thank you so much

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do you have your `<table>` set to width:100%?

This works well on my system when  width is set to 100%.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px; float:right;">
<button>Button 1<button>
<button>Button 2</button>
</td>
</tr><
/table>
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjgCE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the closest parent of those two buttons to have the

`width: 100%; display:flex; justify-content: flex-end;`

Comment: I applied same on td `<td style="width: 100%; display:flex; justify-content: flex-end;">` but no changes i found